# Multi Level Marketing Select and Insert Commision in one Query MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

`--'------------------------------------------
--' TREE 1
--'------------------------------------------
--'                 Company
--'             --------|-------
--'             |              |
--'            A               B
--'       -----|-----      -----|--------
--'       |          |     |            |
--'      AA         AB     BA          BB
--'                      ---|---     ---|---
--'                     |       |    |      |
--'                    BBA    BBB   BBC    BBD
--'------------------------------------------`
Tree 1 is my multi level marketing tree

[image]
**Example :** if BBA get the sales Commission $100, BBA get 60% $60, and BA get 35% $35, B get $5 and company get $10 for the sales commission.

**level 5 most the lowest level**

when a sales success, will insert to tbl_trans, and commission will be calculate end the month, read the tbl_trans and calculate the sales commission divide to all referral and store in tbl_comm.

one transaction at tbl_trans will according tbl_user to create 4 commissions and store in tbl_comm.

this is sample data and table, please help me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8585c

this is what i had tried, but dont have any idea to continue

```
WITH CTE 
AS(
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE User_ID = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT B.*  FROM tbl_user B 
INNER JOIN CTE ON B.User_ID=CTE.User_UplineID)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Look for CTE parent and child that should solve your OP

Comment: @maSTAShuFu can give me the example for my case? and write it on answer

Comment: Cant... im on my mobile. You have to look for it. Not difficult

Comment: In your data, A and B (which are children of Company) are both getting 90% ... Is that a correct data or just a sample? I mean 100 split into 3 parts can be Company 10, A 40, B 50 .... Your example and data are confusing. Can you please correct it so that people can be sure of their understanding of the question you have asked?

Comment: Guy, Updated Question

Comment: is this the case that the tree will only be up to 4 levels but the 1st level then will have expand? so from company they can then have 100 1st levels but only upload 4 level downlines?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b979c/1/0

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_user(
    [User_ID] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [User_Username] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [User_UplineID] INTEGER NULL,
    [User_GivenComm1] INTEGER NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (User_ID)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_user
    ([User_ID], [User_Username],[User_UplineID],[User_GivenComm1])
VALUES
    (1, 'Company',0,10),
    (2, 'B',1,5),
    (3, 'BA',2,25),
    (4, 'BBA',3,60);

CREATE TABLE tbl_trans(
    [trans_ID] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [trans_UserID] INTEGER NULL,
    [trans_SalesComm] [INTEGER] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (trans_ID)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_trans
    ([trans_ID], [trans_UserID],[trans_SalesComm])
VALUES
    (1, 4,125);

CREATE TABLE tbl_comm(
    [comm_ID] INTEGER identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [trans_UserID] INTEGER NULL,
    [trans_ID] INTEGER NULL,
    [trans_CommAmt] [INTEGER] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (comm_ID)
);
```

**CTE to get the parent-child and calculated share**

```
;with myTree as (
   select User_ID,user_username,user_uplineID,trans_SalesComm, User_ID as sourceID, trans_id,User_GivenComm1 from tbl_user y
         inner join tbl_trans x on x.trans_userID = y.user_ID

    union all
    select u.User_ID,u.user_username,u.user_uplineID,t.trans_SalesComm, t.sourceID as sourceID, t.trans_Id,u.User_GivenComm1
          from myTree t
          inner join tbl_user u on
                t.user_uplineID = u.User_ID
 )
  insert into tbl_comm (trans_userID,trans_ID,trans_CommAmt)
  select 
    l.user_ID,
    l.trans_id,
    (l.User_GivenComm1 * 0.01) *  trans_SalesComm
    from myTree l;

  select * from tbl_comm;
```

Comment: No, we are not fixed level percentage commission, i dont need the level share table, each person got their different commission rate

Comment: i make some changes, they commission share column saved to down line data, you can see that 10% commission is stored to B data record.

Comment: and your query where is the insert into tbl_comm ?

Comment: I was pointing out that the commision is based on the level not a static value from the user table... the commision percentage is stored at the levelshares table.. feel free to change but should be able to use the logic

Comment: please change to correct answer? and i can mark as answer...thank you, and please add the insert statement

Comment: your table has userGivencomm1 and comm2 .. how do you use them?

Comment: Sorry, i had updated my question, only got one column, it is givecomm1 only, please re-read my question, it's got minor changes

Comment: all yours now @JohnWalker

Comment: i had make some changes on database design, can you edit the answer?

Comment: what are the changes? you don't update your OP or even fiddler

Comment: Level 5 is the most lower level, level 5 can direct under level 2 as well, see my picture updated, and updated sql fiddle

Comment: good luck. you keep changing your OP. i've wasted a lot of this.

Comment: Sorry, this is last, i promise

Comment: John Walker, Please make sure you are clear about what you want to ask, your question and sqlfiddle are in sync and are updated. It's very difficult to understand ... sqlfiddle still has User_GivenComm2 column as well. Also, B has 2 children - BA and BC so addition of comm percentage always be 100 for children ...isn't it?

Comment: John Walker, Please answer few questions for better understanding :-                             1. what should be the result if BBBA (i.e. Level 5) gets 100$ commission?            2. what should be the result if BA (i.e. Level 3) gets 100$ commission?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, [User_ID] RelatedUserID   FROM tbl_user 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.*, CTE.RelatedUserID FROM tbl_user B 
        INNER JOIN CTE ON B.[User_ID]= CTE.User_UplineID
)
INSERT INTO tbl_comm ([trans_UserID], [trans_ID], [trans_CommAmt])
SELECT CTE.[User_ID], trans_ID,
    CAST( User_GivenComm1 AS decimal(18,2) ) 
        * ( trans_SalesComm / 
            ( SUM( CAST( User_GivenComm1 AS decimal(18,2) ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY trans_ID,RelatedUserID) ) )
as commission
  FROM CTE
    inner join tbl_trans T ON T.trans_UserID = CTE.RelatedUserID
```

Result:

```
comm_ID     trans_UserID trans_ID    trans_CommAmt
----------- ------------ ----------- -------------
1           4            1           60
2           3            1           25
3           2            1           5
4           1            1           10
```

Comment: if User_GivenComm1 and User_GivenComm2 which column is not null then i will use which column, how to do with this condition?

Comment: I assumed, all user comm columns are not null and only one of them has value. but if you have any condition, for example, get max, min or avg, query could change easily

Comment: i had make some changes on database design, can you edit the answer?

Comment: Your description still too confusing. we just need a simple commission percentage calculation formula.